# Powershell: how to loop through folders and execute the same code for each of the folders

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

Currently I have a script that will sort files in a folder (on their lastwritetime), keep the latest file and move the other files to a different folder. This works correctly:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\networkfolder\RawData\2_ActionData_Prep\CustomerA\" -Recurse -Filter "*.rpt" -File |               
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |                                                          
    Move-Item -Force -Destination "\\networkfolder\RawData\_Archive\Archive_DataRetrieved\"
```

The problem is that I have several 'customer' folders and I want to execute the code above in each of those folders.
I tried the following:

```
$CustomerFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\networkfolder\RawData\2_ActionData_Prep\" -Directory -Recurse

foreach ($folder in $CustomerFolders) {Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.rpt" -File | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending  | 
Select-Object -Skip 1 |                                                          
Move-Item -Force -Destination "\\networkfolder\RawData\_Archive\Archive_DataRetrieved\"}
```

When I execute this script, nothing happens. Also no error comes up. Hopefully someone could help me on this.

Santiago Squarzon noticed that a $folder was missing, so I added $folder in loop for Get-Childitem:

```
$CustomerFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\networkfolder\RawData\2_ActionData_Prep\" -Directory -Recurse

foreach ($folder in $CustomerFolders) {Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "*.rpt" -File | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending  | 
Select-Object -Skip 1 |                                                          
Move-Item -Force -Destination "\\networkfolder\RawData\_Archive\Archive_DataRetrieved\"}
```

Now I get an error message:

Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\networkfolder\CustomerA' because it does not exist.

It somehow misses the part \RawData\2_ActionData_Prep\ in the path, although I defined it in the $CustomerFolders variable?

Comment: Seems like you missed `$folder` for `Get-ChildItem` in your loop

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon: thank you for the addition! I added the $folder, but now I am getting an error message that the path does not exist (see above): powershell is looking at the wrong path somehow

Comment: Change `Get-ChildItem $folder ....` to `$folder | Get-ChildItem ....`

Answer (score 1):

You could do the process all with pipelines like this:

```bash
$base = "\\networkfolder\RawData\2_ActionData_Prep\"
$destination = "\\networkfolder\RawData\_Archive\Archive_DataRetrieved\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $base -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.rpt" -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
        Select-Object -Skip 1 | Move-Item -Force -Destination $destination
}
```

To briefly explain why `Get-ChildItem $folder...` failed but `$folder | Get-ChildItem ...` worked, when we do `Get-ChildItem $folder`, `$folder` is being passed as argument for the `-Path` parameter and the [parameter type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#parameter-type) for it is `[string[]]`. So, in your code when `$folder` (a [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0) instance) is passed as argument, it is being converted to a string and, very unfortunately in Windows PowerShell, when we type convert a `DirectoryInfo` (and a [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0) too!) object to string what we get as a result is the **Directory Name** (this is not the case in PowerShell Core, where the string representation of this object becomes the **Directory FullName** (a.k.a. **Absolute Path**) so `Get-ChildItem` thinks it's being fed a *relative path* and it looking for the folders **in your current location**.

However when we do `$folder | Get-ChildItem ...`, `$folder` gets bound to the `-LiteralPath` parameter by [**Property Name**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parameterattribute.valuefrompipelinebypropertyname?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) on the `PSPath` [ETS property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/ets/properties?view=powershell-7.2), in other words, the cmdlet receives the object's [provider path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-7.2) (you can think of it as the absolute path of the folder) hence why it works fine.