# Renaming files inside a folder in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm running this code from a folder at the same path I have a 'testfolder' with some files to try to rename them. When it runs for some reason it comes with an error because the file doesn't exist.

```
param(
    [string]$foldername = 'unknown'
)

if (Test-Path $foldername){
    $amount = Get-ChildItem $foldername | Measure-Object
    $confirmation = Read-Host "All", $amount.Count, "files will be renamed with the name", $newname " Yes/No?" 
    if ($confirmation -eq "Yes"){
        Get-ChildItem  $foldername| ForEach-Object {
            $newname = Read-Host "Pick a new name for a file."
            Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName $newname
    }
        else {Write-Host "Sorry,",$foldername, "does not exist."}
    
    }
}
```

[image: Error]

[image: Folders and files]

I think its trying to rename them and put them at the same path where the script file is running, but it should be inside the folder 'testfolder'

Comment: Change `Rename-Item -Path $_...` for `$_ | Rename-Item...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely to be caused by the [`FileInfo` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-7.0), returned by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2), being coerced into a string and resolved into the file's [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.name?view=net-7.0#system-io-fileinfo-name) (in Windows PowerShell) instead of the file's [FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname?view=net-7.0#system-io-filesysteminfo-fullname). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73792732/15339544) for details, similar issue and a more in depth explanation.

As for your code, it looks like you could leverage [`Cmdlet.ShouldProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.2) to ask for confirmation, [*delay-bind Script Block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) to rename your files and [`ValidateScript` attribute declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validatescript-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2) to validate that the input folder exists:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateScript({
        if(Test-Path $_ -PathType Container) { return $true }
        throw [System.ArgumentException] "'$_' could not be found."
    })]
    [string] $FolderName = 'unknown'
)

$target = $PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($FolderName)
$files  = Get-ChildItem $foldername -File

if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($target, "Renaming $($files.Count) files")) {
    $files | Rename-Item -NewName {
        Read-Host "Pick a new name for $($_.Name)"
    }
}
```

Now when calling your script you would get a prompt like the following:

```
PS ..\pwsh> .\test.ps1 myTestFolder
    
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Renaming 1 files" on target "C:\path\to\myTestFolder".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually does all that I asked for.